# Group and order rows with multiple column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to rows according to same column value.
Suppose this is a table

```
id    name   topic 
1     A      t
2     B      a
3     c      t
4     d      b
5     e      b
6     f      a
```

I want result something like this.

```
id    name   topic
1     A       t
3     c       t
2     B       a
6     f       a
4     d       b
5     e       b
```

As you can see these are not order by topic neither by id, it sort about that topic which come first if `t` come first sort `t` first, one second `a` come then sort according to `a` then `b`.

if you apply `ORDER BY topic` it sort `a b t` or in `DESC` `t b a` but required result is `t a b`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: See FIELD(). Have a nice day.

Comment: So you want to sort rows according to the name associated with the 'first' occurrence of each topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,topic CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'t'),
(2,'a'),
(3,'t'),
(4,'b'),
(5,'b'),
(6,'a');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT topic, MIN(id) id FROM my_table GROUP BY topic ) y 
    ON y.topic = x.topic
 ORDER 
    BY y.id,x.id;
+----+-------+
| id | topic |
+----+-------+
|  1 | t     |
|  3 | t     |
|  2 | a     |
|  6 | a     |
|  4 | b     |
|  5 | b     |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`.

**Query**

```
select * from `your_table_name`
order by 
  case `topic` 
  when 't' then 1 
  when 'a' then 2 
  when 'b' then 3 
  else 4 end
, `name`;
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the names of topic, Suppose user randomly enter any topic

Comment: @AzeemHaider If you don't know the names then how can you know the order?

Comment: Exactly that is my question, If you see id col there `t` start from `id 1` `a` start from `id 2` and `b` start from `id 4` this define the order if somewho we implement this